# Bibliography inside Lyx file?

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex, lyx

LaTeX allows you to place the bibliography inside the document (instead of in a separate .bib file).

Is there a way to achieve something similar with Lyx? Can we manage the bibliography *inside* the .lyx file itself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the layout list (the box in the upper-left), choose "Bibliography". This starts the "thebibliography" environment and inserts the LaTeX code `\bibitem{key-1}`. Here is a screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Thanks. I suppose there is no way to select citation style, etc, in a consistent manner for all the citations?

Comment: I don't think so, but I've never actually used this feature. Off-topic: note that that LyX 2.3.0 (hopefully released by next week) will have native support for Biblatex: https://wiki.lyx.org/LyX/NewInLyX23